# Localization with only IMU

Tags: localization, imu, accelerometer, gyroscope, algorithm

What will be the best approach to get the most localization accuracy out of only an accelerometer and gyroscope?

Comment: Some time ago I read a paper on tracking pedestrians using only shoe-mounted inertial sensors. I can't find it right now, but research in that direction might turn up a few sets of results...

Comment: dont know about localization. but for both sensor accuracy try to implement a filter to the sensor reading. kalman filter/complimentary filter work best i think..

Comment: This question has been asked many times on Robotics StackExchange. Most recently: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/imu-position-without-gps-or-camera .

Answer (score 0):

I believe internal sensors such as those are impossible for localization.  Navigation from a known location is possible with common methods of inertial navigation.  These methods are limited by the accuracy of the sensors and external observations.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to this question: [imu position without GPS or camera](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/8857/imu-position-without-gps-or-camera/8859#8859)

The short answer is that what you ask is not possible given realistic constraints.